# The centralizer of a set $M$ is a closed subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

This is a exercice from the San Martin's book "[Lie Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-61824-7)".

> Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group. Show that the centralizer $$\{g \in G : \forall x \in M,gx=xg\}$$ of the **set** $M$ is a closed subgroup.

I managed to prove the exercise assuming that $M \subset G$, but the exercise does not assume that, in this case, $M$ is any set.

First I thought about using nets, but in this case I got to a point where I need a continuous group action $G\times M \to M$, but since $M$ has no topology, there is no way to prove continuity.

My question is, is it possible to solve this exercise assuming any $M$, or is there some hypothesis missing from the exercise? (*The problem is in proving that the centralizer is closed.*)

**Edit:** To make the question complete, this is exercise 4 of chapter 2 from the referred book.

My initial interpretation was that $M$ was a subgroup of $G$ and so when it was written $gx$ it was referring to group multiplication. So, it is not difficult to observe that
$$\{g \in G : \forall x \in M,gx=xg\}=\bigcap_{x\in M}{C_x^{-1}(\{x\})},$$
where $C_x$ is the conjugation, $C_x(g)=gxg^{-1}$. From the fact that it is Hausdorff, we have that the centralizer will be closed.

Now, having the interpretation that we are talking about any action, for the example cited by Rob Arthan, it is necessary to assume the continuity of the action. But in this case, to conclude that it is a subgroup, I believe it is necessary to talk about the [compatibility](https://mathoverflow.net/a/106261) of actions on the right and left.

Comment: I don't think that the question makes sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My question or the exercise?

Comment: The exercise. The notation $xg$, with $x\in M$ and $g\in G$, suggests that we have a right action here, besides the left action $(g,x)\mapsto gx$. But the statement of the exercise says nothing about that. And the author says that he will with left actions only.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I don't have access to the book, but even if the author did work with left and right actions so that the exercise makes some kind of sense, I don't think it can be right without some assumptions on continuity - see my answer. Do you agree?

Comment: The way the exercise was proposed caused me a lot of confusion, but assuming $M \subset G$, it was possible to use Proposition 2.22 (from the same book), because of this proposition I thought of this additional assumption.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I agree.

Comment: From the context and having a look at the book, it's quite clear that the author assumes that $M$ is a subset of $G$ (and should have written it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the group actions on $M$ here must be required to be continuous. To get a counterexample to the claim as stated, take $G = \Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$, a countable product of copies of the additive group $\Bbb{R}$, and equip it with the product topology. Define:
$$
\begin{align*}
H = \{g \in G \mid \forall i \in \Bbb{N}, g_{2i} = 0\} \\
K = \{g \in G \mid \forall i \in \Bbb{N}, g_{3i} = 0\}
\end{align*}
$$
Let $\pi_H : G \to H$ be the projection homomorphism that replaces coordinates with even indexes by $0$ and let $\pi_K : G \to K$ be the projection homomorphism that replaces coordinates with indexes that are multiples of $3$ by $0$.
Now define actions of $G$ on itself by:
$$
\begin{align*}
gx &= \pi_H(g) + x\\
xg &= \pi_K(g) + x
\end{align*}
$$

Then $gx = xg$ iff $\pi_H(g) = \pi_K(g)$ iff $g \in H \cap K$. So taking taking $M = G$ in your question with the above actions, we have that the "centralizer" of $M$ is $H \cap K$, but $H \cap K$ is not a closed subgroup of $G$.

**Addendum**

Mrcrg's edit raised the purely algebraic question of how to ensure this generalised centralizer is a subgroup of $G$ and proposed a compatibility condition that is certainly sufficient.

To see that some condition is necessary, we get an example where the generalised centralizer is not a group by taking $G = S_3$ and $M = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. For $g \in G$ and $i \in M$, define
$$
\begin{align*}
gi &= g(i) \\
ig &= g^{-1}(i)
\end{align*}
$$
Then these are left and right group actions. The generalised centralizer is the set of $g \in G$ such that $g = g^{-1}$ and this is not closed under products: the transpositions $(1\;2)$ and $(2\;3)$ are in the generalised centralizer, but their product is a $3$-cycle and is not.

However, the compatibility condition is not necessary for the generalised centralizer to be a subgroup, as may be seen by considering the cyclic groups $C_2$ and $C_3$, which I will take to be represented as the subgroups of $S_3$ generated by $(1\;2)$ and $(1\;2\;3)$ respectively. If we then take $G = C_2 \times C_3$, we can define actions of $G$ on $\Bbb{Z}^3$ by:

$$
\begin{align*}
(a, b) (i_1, i_2, i_3) &= (i_{a(1)}, i_{a(2)}, i_3) \\
(i_1, i_2, i_3)(a, b)  &= (i_{b(1)}, i_{b(2)}, i_{b(3)}) \\
\end{align*}
$$

Then these are left and right actions and they aren't compatible, but the generalised centralizer comprises only the identity of $G$ and so is a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Well, assuming the action in M is continuous would allow me to use nets to complete the exercise. As it stands, I couldn't think of any way to prove it, and given your example, I now know there's no way.

Comment: I made a small comment on the question to make it more complete. And then another question came to me. To show that the centralizer is a subgroup, I believe it is still necessary to assume the compatibility between the actions on the right and left.

Comment: I am sure you are right that the compatibility condition is necessary to show that the the "centraliser" is a group, but I don't have a counterexample to hand. I will see if I can come up with one.

Comment: In fact, some condition is necessary, but compatibility is sufficient but not necessary. See the examples I have added to the answer. I suspect there will be no succinct or very useful necessary and sufficient condition.